# Drivers lost. Reinstalling Ubuntu, not acces to parallel Windows and no wifi/ethernet

Tags: wireless, drivers, windows, reinstalling

Excuse me for this thread maybe not well suited here. I had Windows Vista and Ubuntu 14.04 on my Dell Inspiron 1545 dual core. Main use Ubuntu. Some months ago it started to have problems and it has been a while since the last update (this terrible I know). Between personal and working-moving issues I didn't get to solve it complete.

Yesterday the internet connection broke down completely and the Ubuntu interface looked rare, with another letter format and so on. I urgently need it for work.
So reading some forums the best choice given my situation was to reinstall. So I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and that's OK. So now I'm here:
1) Not wireless nor ethernet connection on Ubuntu.
2) Not able to start on Windows.

I have the installation CDs but my DVD reader doesn't work.
Could someone advice me how to move now? I now there is probably too much info on the web, but I really don't know where to look or start. Writing from phone now. And limited acces to another's one PC and my own USB booted with installation of Ubuntu. Now checking for sure if Windows doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same happened to me. The solution is really simple. If drivers worked in the past, they probably still do. Try unplugging the wifi adapter and plug it again. It is more complicated with a laptop though.

edit: for the windows not booting, I can only think of getting the iso version of windows and using the repair option, that'll probably work.

Comment: Almoust solved. I tried to repair Windows but didn't work. To do that I had to use the DVD-Installer which fortunately I have. The bad is that my CD/DVD lector is broken. So I made an ISO from the DVD-Installer (from another computer with internet, this was unavoidable) and with the ISO booted an USB. Installed Windows (need for software hard to install or run in Linux) so far and now partitioning through my second experience with UBUNTU